# How can I reset servo position?

Tags: servo

When I do

```
myServo.write(0)
```

It isn't straight, I want it to be straight but it is at about a 45 degree angle anyone know how to reset the position with arduino to make other positions 0 and making everything relative to where that zero is?

Comment: The easy way is to remove the servo arm, set the servo position with the Arduino, and then put the servo arm back on.

Comment: if the servo class is designed to go from 0 to some maximum, then it's correct that a typical servo should be at 45 degrees (and it should be at 45 degrees the other way when you ask for maximum).  Typical modern servos have splined output shafts that are easy to reset.

Comment: On Arduino, 0 is 90 degrees one way,  90 is centered, and 180 is 90 degrees in the other direction. Not all servos can do 180 degrees so the actual maximum rotation may be less.

Comment: What kind of servo? And reference angle ?